# mysqli object oriented real escape string

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to Mysqli and PHP and want to learn to use object oriented code instead of procedural. I am struggling however to convert mysqli_real_escape_string to the object oriented way. In the code below I have used the procedural code because I don't know how to use the object oriented way and Google searches are not providing the answers I am looking for.

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM `users` WHERE email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."'LIMIT 1";

        $result = $link->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0) {

        echo "The email " .$_POST['email']. " is already taken";

    } else {

        echo $_POST['email'];
    }


}
```

In the real world I would have some sort of validation on the input fields but for learning purposes for myself, I have no validation. That being said, if someone was to go to the registration page, they could use SQL injection. I am trying to prevent that in the code that checks if the email address exists. From what I have read, mysqli_real_escape_string is used to prevent SQL injection and using something like htmlspecialchars would be used to prevent XSS. I am trying to prevent SQL injection in this particular example.

Comment: `string mysqli::escape_string ( string $escapestr )` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php `string mysqli::real_escape_string ( string $escapestr )` ^ RTM.

Comment: You should also space this out `$_POST['email'])."'LIMIT` as that stands to read as `email@example.comLIMIT 1`, in turn, causing a syntax error. So, `$_POST['email'])."' LIMIT 1`

Comment: The better way would be to use prepared statements

Comment: I have code on how to use a prepared statement to insert a record from W3 schools but not to select data. I am still trying to work that out.

Comment: It's essentially the same. Prepare, bind data, execute. And for select, fetch your data after execution.

Comment: so, [comment #2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181811/mysqli-object-oriented-real-escape-string#comment65705070_39181811); what have you to say about it? or was that just a bad paste? you'll need to ping me directly, I won't stay here for much longer.

Comment: Sorry, but I tried helping here. I'm done.

Comment: Sorry, Fred. I am not getting an error on my page saying I have a syntax error as you mentioned below. I created the space as you said and it made no difference whatsoever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of OO you use `$link->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])`. In your example you use `mysqli_reql_escape_string` the procedural way.

> I see:
>
> `<script>alert("Here is an alert");</script>`
>
> **instead of all the weir &alt stuff that I should be seeing if I had done this correctly**.

For the second part, i think **you're mistaking** `real_escape_string` and `html_special_chars`.
`mysqli_real_escape_string` **does not convert entities**, oposite to `html_special_chars`.

SQL does not need to special characters converted to entities since. You can't *expect* `mysqli_real_escape_string` to return you encoded entities.

In Short, you **do not** need entities encoded for mysql query. Only mysql special characters that could "harm" query

Comment: So, are you saying because I am not actually inserting data I don't need to use real_escape_string but rather htmlspecialchars?

Comment: I sure hope that that isn't what he's saying. I honestly don't know why people are posting answers about html_special_chars and htmlentities. @Jonathan  You posted this comment *"I am just trying to check if the email address the user inputs matches anything in the database"* under another answer. If you're trying to do just that, then your question is unclear at this point and you haven't even replied to a comment I left you up there. So again; if you want to resolve this matter; ping me. You have a syntax error in your code and I told what it was, should that be your real code.

Comment: It isn't what I'm saying. Im saying you want to do it OO way. The first part of question.
2nd Part of question suggest, that you expect real_escape_string to return &alt; (entities). I'm saying that real_escape_string does not do that. Mysql does not need it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Edited answer for you and clarification. Question does not only consist of title.

Comment: @Grzegorz I for one have no idea what they're asking after seeing the question and comments left and scattered about by the OP. First they're asking about doing it the OOP way, then it's about checking if a row exists; I'm quite puzzled TBH.

Comment: I am sorry if everything I am saying is confusing. I am going to edit my question and hopefully that will help.

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_real_escape_string is just meant to use a string from user space in database query safely (known as SQL injection attacks). In your case the email (that js code) is inserted correctly into DB. You could even use ' instead of " now without getting an Mysql error.

But what you want to do is display data from user space in an HTML website, which needs another, different modification to prevent cross-site-scripting: https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.htmlentities.php

**tl;dr:**

`mysqli_real_escape_string` (or its OOP equivalent) escapes characters that cause problems in a database query like `'` becoming `\'`

`htmlentities` changes characters to the corresponding html entity, ie. `<` is converted to `&lt;`

Comment: I am just trying to check if the email address the user inputs matches anything in the database

Comment: but do you really have a record in your database with `email = <script>alert("Here is an alert");</script>` and you MUST always use real_escape_string when you use a variable from user space in ANY query.

Comment: No, I am just pretending to be a hacker who could go to my user registration page and input some evil javascript to do something nasty. So, I am just trying to prevent that. That javascript alert doesn't exist in my database.

Comment: My issue is getting the query right. I tried what Grzegorz suggested but it doesn't work still 
 $sql = "SELECT email FROM `users` WHERE email = '".$link->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."' LIMIT 1";